# Trying to format ipv6 string using ctypes

Tags: python, ipv6

I am having trouble getting an ipv6 address formatting into a packed binary string. After doing some digging, it appears that `socket.inet_pton(...)` does not work in windows. While digging, I came across a suggestion to use ctypes and the [InetPton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function built into `Ws2_32.dll`. Below is my simple script:

```
import ctypes
import socket

a = ctypes.WinDLL("ws2_32.dll") 

in_addr_p = ctypes.create_string_buffer("200f::")
out_addr_p = ctypes.create_string_buffer(40)

a.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, in_addr_p, out_addr_p)
print "Input: {}".format(repr(in_addr_p.raw))
print "Output: {}".format(repr(out_addr_p.raw))
```

When I run it, I get the following:

```
Input: '200f::\x00'
Output: ' \x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00
```

I am stumped as to why it appears that "F" is the only character that makes it through the conversion process.
'

Comment: First, there's no "F" making it through the conversion; the first character is a space the second character is `\x0F`—aka, an invisible ctrl-O—and the rest are `\x00`—aka, invisible NUL bytes.

Comment: Now, if you look at the bytes, they're 0x20, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00, …, 0x00. Which is… exactly what they should be, right? So what's the problem here?

Comment: 0x20 is a space, so the conversion is indeed correct

Comment: Ah yes, I completely overlooked those little spaces. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 4):

See that space at the beginning of `' \x0f...'`? That's where the `'20'` ended up, as `\x20` is rendered as a space. So your code is working just fine...

If you're using python3.3 or newer, you should consider using the [ipaddress](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ipaddress) module for such operations. There should also be [backports](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=ipaddress&submit=search) for python2.

Comment: If I could +1 again for adding the recommendation of the `ipaddress` backport, I would.